# Unable to find template - moved Resources from AppBundle to app folder

Tags: symfony

I moved the Resources/ twig templates from AppBundle to the app folder and now I got:

```
Unable to find template "ItemBundle:Category:index.html.twig".
```

I already changed the Routes in the Annotations for the Controllers, but where can I changed the default behaviour for index.html.twig, because the alway want to look at the Bundle, but there is no Bundle anymore, it's just the app folder.

```
/**
     * Lists all Category entities.
     *
     * @Route("/", name="category")
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Template(":Category:index.html.twig")
     */
```

I don't want to change all @Template - Just explain, that all stuff is now under app folder and than the normal CRUD way. For the normal CRUD way, I don't need to write down each @Template where to find the twig template.

Comment: Did you actually move it? You shouldn't move anything in vendor packages, only copy. The fix is easy enough, just `composer update`

Comment: I didn't move in vendor, it's my own Bundle.

Comment: What's your path to the template (starting at `app`)? It should be something like `app/Resources/ItemBundle/Category/index.html.twig` if you're trying to override it.

Comment: I already override it in the Controller, but for global, Symfony alway looking at the AppBundle. So when I open /category, I got this error, because he is looking at the AppBundle.

Comment: If you're trying to directly link to it and not override it, then use `::index.html.twig`. See [doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#template-naming-locations) for more information.

Comment: I already did this, this is not the point. The point is, that he can't find the Resource file, because of the default behavior.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding how those template references resolve.  [Here's the relevant documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#template-naming-locations)

When you use something like `ItemBundle:Category:index.html.twig` that means Symfony will try to find that template in two places, in this order

1. app/Resources/**ItemBundle**/views/**Category**/**index.html.twig**
2. src/**ItemBundle**/Resources/views/**Category**/**index.html.twig**

So this is going to depend on where you moved them *to*.  So let's say for example that you moved this one twig file to **app/Resources/views/Category/index.html.twig**. Make note of how this is different than #1 above - the template is no longer in a bundle directory - just a sub-directory of the root views directory.

Therefore, the proper references is `::Category/index.html.twig`

Comment: Thank you for your help! Really sorry, this is simply not the answer to my question. It is not about making an link to another twig file from a twig file. It is about the controller: * `@Template(":Category:index.html.twig")` is correct, but this is only the first step and did not solve my problem.

Comment: Can you tell me exactly where you moved your twig files to? What's the full path?

Comment: By my he is only looking at `src/ItemBundle/Resources/views/Category/index.html.twig` - find here nothing and throw Unable to find template.
@Peter Bailey: 
The full path is: `app/Resources/views/Category/`

Comment: Then you put them in the wrong place. If you want `:Category:index.html.twig` to still work, then you need to move your files into `app/Resources/ItemBundle/views/Category`.

Comment: Sorry, a error in my question ItemBundle is the wrong name, it is `CheckoutItemBundle` and `CheckoutItemBundle` it just the short name. My folder structure was `src/Checkout/Bundle/ItemBundle/Resources/views/Category` - tried to change it in `app/Checkout/Bundle/ItemBundle/Resources/views/Category` still not working...

Comment: You are not paying attention to the details of what I'm saying. When you want to place templates in `app/Resources/` then you must create a subdirectory based on the **bundle's name**.  That would be `app/Resources/CheckoutItemBundle/views/Category`

Comment: Thank you for your patience. You are absolutely right. Now it's all working.

Comment: Is there a change in this with Symfony 3? Im using PhpStorm and have this directory src\AppBundle\Resources\views\Login\login.html.twig giving me error as "Unable to find template "AppBundle:Login:login.html.twig" (looked into: C:\Users\pvd45397\PhpstormProjects\TestSite1\tutorial01\app/Resources/views, C:\Users\pvd45397\PhpstormProjects\TestSite1\tutorial01\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bridge\Twig/Resources/views/Form). "